# Change selector in event handler

Tags: javascript, handler, jquery

How to change the selector event handler? 
Function refreshThreshold() changes the frequency of triple mouse clicks.

My code does not work. More precisely, by changing the variable "thresholdVal" does not change the frequency of clicks ("threshold: thresholdVal" selector ).

Processing script tripleclick taken from here: 
https://github.com/richadams/jquery-tripleclick

```
function refreshThreshold() {
    thresholdVal = $( "#trippleclickSlider" ).slider( "value" );
    console.log(thresholdVal);
}

var thresholdVal = 1000;
$("#div").on("tripleclick", { threshold: thresholdVal }, function()
{
//any process
});
```

Comment: Locked. Prompted to look into the script triple clicks. Forgot to specify the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like the on tripleclick listener merely stores the value instead of referencing the variable.

Try changing your refreshThreshold() function to additionally reset the listener (re-call div.ontripleclick)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to use the .off() and .unbind() to reset the listener, but only got an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined". Linked to trippleclick script. This means that is need to refine the script itself? Or is there another way?

Comment: Thanks for the help!
The code was an error, so it was impossible to do .off()